# Background Color Covers Border in Table Rotated Cell Only

Tags: border, background-color, overlap

I have a Table in which some cells are rotated

For instance :

`<th rowspan="13" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(-180deg); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 5px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 0.9em; background-color: #fff7e6;">Radial</th>`

Table formatting is as follows :

`<table style="border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-collapse: collapse; max-width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 4vh; margin-bottom: 6vh; text-align: center; font-family: 'Calibri', sanserif;">`

No formatting for rows

Background color - **in these rotated cells only** - will overlap and cover a border line like border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;

- In Firefox, overlap is on the bottom border of the rotated cell
- In Edge, overlap is on the bottom border of the top neighbor cell - rotated or not
- In Chrome, the issue is not there

Overlap size = 1px only (if border thickness set to 2px, 1px becomes visible)

I have read different ancient discussions regarding how to overcome a similar bug for not-rotated cells, like using the background-clip property
But none of the solutions will work here

Does anyone have some idea ?
Thanks